# C Minishell Command Expansion Printing Gibberish

Tags: c, shell, command, expansion

I'm writing a unix minishell in C, and am at the point where I'm adding command expansion. What I mean by this is that I can nest commands in other commands, for example:

```
$> echo hello $(echo world! ... $(echo and stuff))
hello world! ... and stuff
```

I think I have it working mostly, however it isn't marking the end of the expanded string correctly, for example if I do:

```
$> echo a $(echo b $(echo c))
a b c
$> echo d $(echo e)
d e c
```

See it prints the c, even though I didn't ask it to. Here is my code:

msh.c - http://pastebin.com/sd6DZYwB
expand.c - http://pastebin.com/uLqvFGPw

I have a more code, but there's a lot of it, and these are the parts that I'm having trouble with at the moment. I'll try to tell you the basic way I'm doing this.

Main is in msh.c, here it gets a line of input from either the commandline or a shellfile, and then calls processline (char *line, int outFD, int waitFlag), where line is the line we just got, outFD is the file descriptor of the output file, and waitFlag tells us whether or not we should wait if we fork. When we call this from main we do it like this:

```
processline (buffer, 1, 1);
```

In processline, we allocate a new line:

```
char expanded_line[EXPANDEDLEN];
```

We then call expand, in expand.c:

```
expand(line, expanded_line, EXPANDEDLEN);
```

In expand, we copy the characters literally from line to expanded_line until we find a $(, which then calls:

```
static int expCmdOutput(char *orig, char *new, int *oldl_ind, int *newl_ind)
```

orig is line, and new is expanded line. oldl_ind and newl_ind are the current positions in the line and expanded line, respectively. Then we pipe, and recursively call processline, passing it the nested command(for example, if we had "echo a $(echo b)", we would pass processline "echo b").

This is where I get confused, each time expand is called, is it allocating a new chunk of memory EXPANDEDLEN long? If so, this is bad because I'll run out of stack room really quickly(in the case of a hugely nested commandline input). In expand I insert a null character at the end of the expanded string, so why is it printing past it?

If you guys need any more code, or explanations, just ask. Secondly, I put the code in pastebin because there's a ton of it, and in my experience people don't like it when I fill up several pages with code.

Comment: I took a look at the code, and it is too big to encourage scrutiny. You probably aren't adding a null pointer at the end of an argument list somewhere. You should try some alternative sequences which echo more than one argument in the inner echo commands. I'm going to recommend some generic debugging techniques. One possibility is to simply run the code under the debugger. I tend to use the older school 'insert print statements' techniques. I'd add the print statements to where I can detect where the extra argument is added, or the NULL pointer is not set.  Good luck.

Comment: I think I've pin pointed it a bit more since I posted this. When I do exec("echo"), I expected it to insert a null character after its output. How do I write a single null character at the spot where echo stopped writing? I think that would fix my entire problem here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in `expCmdOutput`. As you already noticed, you do not get NUL terminated strings when reading the output of your child process using `read`. What you want to do is terminate the string manually, by adding something like

```
    buf[bytes_read] = '\0';
```

after your call to `read` in line 29 (expand.c). Sicne you need space for the NUL, you can only read up to `BUF_SIZE - 1` bytes then, of course.

You should probably rethink the whole loop you do afterwards, though:

```
    /* READ OUTPUT OF COMMAND FROM READ END OF PIPE, THEN CLOSE READ END */
    bytes_read = read(fd[0],buf,BUF_SIZE);
    while(bytes_read > 0)
    {
            bytes_read = read(fd[0], buf, BUF_SIZE);
            if (bytes_read == -1) perror("read");
    }
    close(fd[0]);
```

If the output of your command is longer than BUF_SIZE, you simply read again to `buf`, overwriting the output you just read. What you really want here is to allocate memory and append to the end using `strcat` (or by holding a pointer to the end of your string for efficiency).